# google cloud storage tried to access method com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getFromServiceLoader error

Tags: servlets, google-cloud-storage, pom.xml, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to test google cloud storage in local mvn jetty server.
defining the following java servlet I get the following error during servlet initiallization.

```
@WebServlet(name = "receiveImage", value = "receiveImage")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@MultipartConfig()
public class receiveImage extends HttpServlet {


private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "testbucket";
private  static Storage storage = null;


@Override
public void init() {


    storage = StorageOptions.defaultInstance().service();



}
```

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /receiveImage. Reason:

```
Server Error
```

Caused by:

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getFromServiceLoader(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; from class com.google.cloud.HttpServiceOptions
    at com.google.cloud.HttpServiceOptions.(HttpServiceOptions.java:154)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.(StorageOptions.java:69)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.(StorageOptions.java:27)
    at com.google.cloud.sto

i define the following maven dependency in pom file:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
<version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Appreciate for helps.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue: 
there is a conflict between these two dependencies:

```
dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>gcloud-java-datastore</artifactId>
   <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
   <version>0.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I just changed the first dependency to

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
   <version>0.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```